# Как выбрать колонки в DataFrame по списку?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, обработка-данных

Нужно по списку выбрать определенные колонки в DataFrame.

Cписок c колонками:

```
lst = ['JOHN', 'GARRY']
```

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'JOHN': [1111, 2222, 3333], 'EMMA': [1234, 6666, None], 'GARRY': [5555, 5678, 7777]})
```

Я знаю как выбрать указав конкретные колонки, но как сделать из списка, не могу сообразить:

```
df = df[['JOHN', 'GARRY']]
```

Comment: можно и `df[lst]`, но вариант с `loc` идеологически правильней.

Comment: @higot4625, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

**Вариант 1:** наиболее идиоматический:

```
In [144]: df.loc[:, lst]
Out[144]:
   JOHN  GARRY
0  1111   5555
1  2222   5678
2  3333   7777
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
In [145]: df[lst]
Out[145]:
   JOHN  GARRY
0  1111   5555
1  2222   5678
2  3333   7777
```

---

**Вариант 3:** можно использовать если в списке столбцов есть такие, которые не встречаются в DataFrame - это позволит обойти ошибку `KeyError`:

```
In [146]: df.filter(lst + ['N/A'])
Out[146]:
   JOHN  GARRY
0  1111   5555
1  2222   5678
2  3333   7777
```

**Вариант 4:** можно использовать если в списке столбцов есть такие, которые не встречаются в DataFrame - это позволит обойти ошибку `KeyError`:

```
In [148]: df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(['AAA', 'JOHN', 'GARRY'])]
Out[148]:
   JOHN  GARRY
0  1111   5555
1  2222   5678
2  3333   7777
```

**NOTE:** варианты 3 и 4 позволяют использовать списки, содержащие несуществующие столбцы (см. вариант 4 для примера).